# Global Search does not find emails marked as spam

Tags: thunderbird

### My problem:

I searched for an (important) email with Ctrl+k in Thunderbird. It didn't find the email. After some time I found out that Gloabl search omits emails which are marked as spam like this:
[image]

### My setup:

Thunderbird Version 115.8.1 (64-Bit) on Windows 11

### My question:

How can I setup thunderbird in a way that the gloabl search also finds emails marked as junk?

Comment: +1 clearly stated, with documentation

Answer (score 2):

From Thunderbird's
[Global Search](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/global-search) :

> **Searching for spam and deleted messages**
>
> Trash and Spam folders are not searched by default. You may override
> this behavior for individual folders:
>
> 1. Right-click such a folder.
> 2. Click **Properties** in the context menu that opens.
> 3. Check the box next to **Include messages in this folder in Global Search results**.
> 4. Click **OK**.